# Calculate points for borders inside and outside of a polygon

Tags: ios, graphics, core-graphics, cgpath

In my code I get some set of points that define a simple polygon. I need to draw the polygon itself, as well as a border inside and outside of it

If it was a rectangle, I could simply use CGRectInset() on iOS. However, it isn't a rectangle.

So I need an algorithm that provides me the inner and outer borders from a simple polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath).

Comment: that's just a copy. how does this help to create inner / outer borders?

Comment: It's not “just a copy”.  It's the outline of the area that would be filled if you stroked the path.  Thus (for a polygon) it is in fact two subpaths, one offset into the interior of the original and the other offset into the exterior.